# CSV file saving in array with realloc

Tags: c, file, csv, pointers, realloc

I have problem with reading data from csv file and saving it into the array. I want to do it in a function. Values are good in function (reading works well), but values in the main are not. I think it's a problem with pointers in reallocating process (I might lose some of those). Here's my code and pls help.

```
void read_from_csv(FILE* file ,double **tab, int *size)  
{
    int i = 0;
    double A, B;
    double *temp;
    while (fscanf(file, "%lf;%lf\n", &A, &B) != EOF)
    {
        i += 2;
        temp = realloc(*tab, i*sizeof(**tab));
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            *tab = temp;
            *size = i;
            **(tab + i - 2) = A;
            **(tab + i - 1) = B;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nERROR");
            temp = NULL;
        }   
    }
}
```

And I call it in the main like this:

```
file = fopen("file.csv", "r");

read_from_csv(file,&tab,&size);

fclose(file);
```

tab is allocated in main earlier as

```
double *tab;
tab = malloc(1*sizeof(*tab));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double *tab;
tab = malloc(1*sizeof(*tab));

temp = realloc(*tab, i*sizeof(**tab));
```

These allocate space for pointers, but you're storing doubles which are typically larger. So you need...

```
tab = malloc(1*sizeof(*tab));

temp = realloc(*tab, i * sizeof(double));
```

---

```
**(tab + i - 2) = A;
**(tab + i - 1) = B;
```

This also isn't quite right. It's adding to the address of `tab`, which points at a pointer, and then trying stick 2 doubles where there's only space for one pointer.

Instead you want to add to `*tab`, the address of the allocated memory, and dereference that.

```
*(*tab + i - 2) = A;
*(*tab + i - 1) = B;
```

Using `*tab` as an array does the same thing and is much easier to read.

```
(*tab)[i - 2] = A;
(*tab)[i - 1] = B;
```

---

```
while (fscanf(file, "%lf;%lf\n", &A, &B) != EOF)
```

This also isn't quite right. If it always sees the right input it's fine. But if it sees something it doesn't expect it will hang. `fscanf` will not advance the cursor if its parsing fails. It will repeatedly read the same bad line over and over again. And whatever garbage is in `A` and `B` will go into `tab`. This is one of the many issues with [`scanf` and `fscanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Instead, separate reading the from parsing the line using `fgets` and `sscanf`. This avoids garbage data and allows better handling of bad lines.

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
{
    if( sscanf(line, "%lf;%lf\n", &A, &B) != 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s could not be parsed\n", line);
        continue;
    }

    ...
}
```